# App windows 8 hash md5

Tags: md5, winjs

I need to calculate the md5 of a file saved locally in an windows8 app  created in 
javascript / html.

I need the md5 to compare it with an online file and see if the two objects are really the same.

What function should I use?

Answer (score 1):

Here's the code I use to hash a string in MD5 using Windows.Security.Cryptography namespace:

```
var inputBuffer, outputBuffer, toHash, hashed,
    hashProvider = Windows.Security.Cryptography.Core.HashAlgorithmProvider.openAlgorithm(Windows.Security.Cryptography.Core.HashAlgorithmNames.md5); // "open" an md5 hash provider

toHash = 'string'; // string to hash
inputBuffer = Windows.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicBuffer.convertStringToBinary(toHash, Windows.Security.Cryptography.BinaryStringEncoding.utf8); // convert string to binary
outputBuffer = hashProvider.hashData(inputBuffer); // hash the binary
hashed = Windows.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicBuffer.encodeToHexString(outputBuffer); // the hashed string
```

Now, all you need to do is to read the file in (see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh464978.aspx). If reading the file into a buffer, then you wouldn't need the convertStringToBinary line.

Answer (score 0):

The WinRT API provides SHA functionality in the Windows.Security.Cryptography.Core namespace, specifically through the static method `HashAlgorithmProvider.openAlgorithm(Windows.Security.Cryptography.Certificates.HashAlgorithmNames.sha256)`.

This provides you with a HashAlgorithmProvider class that has methods like hashData.

Fin in [this Link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.security.cryptography.core.aspx) is all that's available in winjs in terms of cryptography.

And [Here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsapps/en-US/d618343c-76fb-40fd-9ef0-12dfb23de235/is-there-any-rsa-sha-api-in-winrt-javascript?forum=winappswithhtml5) you can find an example on how to implement an MD5 calculator for a string, from there is a good start to make it work for a file.

Hope this helps.

Comment: i don't understand how to use the method in javascript!